# How JDK 8's type inference works with generic?

Tags: java, generics, java-8, type-inference

I have code which is failed to compile with JDK 7 but succeed to compile with JDK 8.

To abstract actual code:

```
interface A {
...
}

class B implements A {
...
}

public void AAA(List<A> list) {...}

AAA(Collections.singletonList(new B()));
```

Collections.singletonList is defined as

```
public static <T> List<T> singletonList(T o) {
    return new SingletonList<>(o);
}
```

So as far as I know based on generic, T will be inferred to B, so Collections.singletonList(new B()) will be List which cannot be assigned to List since Java generic is invariant.

But with JDK 8, T is inferred to A and compilation succeeds.

I'd like to know how T is inferred to A, since there're two variables here for type T: A and B.

Is there order of priority? Or does compiler find common ancestor class?

Attaching official document is more appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

ps1. The version of JDK 7 is Oracle 1.7.0_79 and the version of JDK 8 is Oracle 1.8.0_66.

ps2. Here's the links for actual code:

https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/85a31e2fdec1ffef83e1ff438cd765a821fb06e4/examples/storm-opentsdb-examples/src/main/java/org/apache/storm/opentsdb/SampleOpenTsdbBoltTopology.java#L48

https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/85a31e2fdec1ffef83e1ff438cd765a821fb06e4/external/storm-opentsdb/src/main/java/org/apache/storm/opentsdb/bolt/OpenTsdbBolt.java#L77

https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/85a31e2fdec1ffef83e1ff438cd765a821fb06e4/external/storm-opentsdb/src/main/java/org/apache/storm/opentsdb/bolt/TupleOpenTsdbDatapointMapper.java#L37

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, there is an entire new chapter, [§18. Type Inference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html), in the language specification, but it’s not an easy read. Even the first section’s summary, addressing exactly your question, is tough:

> In comparison to the Java SE 7 Edition of The Java® Language Specification, important changes to inference include:
>
> - Adding support for lambda expressions and method references as method invocation arguments.
> - Generalizing to define inference in terms of poly expressions, which may not have well-defined types until after inference is complete. This has the notable effect of improving inference for nested generic method and diamond constructor invocations.
> - Describing how inference is used to handle wildcard-parameterized functional interface target types and most specific method analysis.
> - Clarifying the distinction between invocation applicability testing (which involves only the invocation arguments) and invocation type inference (which incorporates a target type).
> - Delaying resolution of all inference variables, even those with lower bounds, until invocation type inference, in order to get better results.
> - Improving inference behavior for interdependent (or self-dependent) variables.
> - Eliminating bugs and potential sources of confusion. This revision more carefully and precisely handles the distinction between specific conversion contexts and subtyping, and describes reduction by paralleling the corresponding non-inference relations. Where there are intentional departures from the non-inference relations, these are explicitly identified as such.
> - Laying a foundation for future evolution: enhancements to or new applications of inference will be easier to integrate into the specification.

The second bullet has the biggest impact on your code example. You have a nested method invocation of a generic method without specifying explicit type arguments, which makes it a so-called *poly expression* whose actual type might be inferred from the *target type*, which is the parameter type of `AAA` in your case.

So this is a rather easy constellation as `AAA` isn’t generic and no ambiguity regarding it’s parameter type. It’s always `List<A>`. There is no search for a “common ancestor class” here, all that has to be checked, is whether the argument expression’s type (`B`) is compatible with the inferred type (`A`).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Yeah, looking at jls doc seems really touch just for curious. I've followed the link and more depth to skim but can't understand at all. :) Your answer looks like having enough depth. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

This is actually explained [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html) at the end at **Target Types**.

Target Type has been expanded to include method argument ...

What this means is that

```
 AAA(Collections.singletonList(new B())); // returns List<A> NOT List<B>
```

In jdk-7 method argument is **not** used to find out the target type, that is why T is inferred to B and that is why it fails.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I read the doc before but was not clear since the example uses Collections.emptyList(), which doesn't input another type hint. From what you described, it is just a order of priority and A is always prior to B?

Answer (score 0):

At "target types" section of http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html

It says

> This is no longer necessary in Java SE 8. The notion of what is a target type has been expanded to include method arguments, such as the argument to the method processStringList.

Your method AAA expects list of type A, so I believe as long as the type you provided for calling AAA() is typecasting available or subtype of A, Java8's target types is going to pick up A over B based on the hint you give in the code?

Comment: Thanks for answering, this seems duplicated with Eugene's answer.